# angular forms 'confirm password' showing error

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formbuilder

I am using angular forms to create a register form. 
I have made a custom validator which checked if the password is the same as confirm password field. Although the error of 'password do not match' does not show, the input is still red until all the fields are entered.

The form builder with the custom validator method `checkPasswords`

```js
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  firstName: ['', Validators.required],
  lastName: ['', Validators.required],
  email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
  password: ['', [Validators.required]],
  confirmPassword: ['', [Validators.required]]
  },
  { validator: this.checkPasswords });


checkPasswords(group: FormGroup) {
  // here we have the 'passwords' group
  let pass = group.get('password').value;
  let confirmPassword = group.get('confirmPassword').value;
  return pass === confirmPassword ? null : { notSame: true };
}
```

and the html below

```html
<mat-form-field required>
    <input matInput type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password">
    <mat-error>Password is not valid</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field required>
    <input matInput type="password" placeholder="Confirm password"
           formControlName="confirmPassword"
           [errorStateMatcher]="matcher">
    <mat-error *ngIf="registerForm.hasError('notSame')">Passwords do not match</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

I have tried to do some debugging, and I think it is because the form group status is 'invalid' until all fields are entered, but the form group control for `confirmPassword` is showing valid. 
How can I get status for confirmPassword to use the status of its control?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a working sample on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)

Comment: Not entirely sure what the question is…if you're wondering why `confirmPassword` initially shows as valid, it's because initially, both `password` and `confirmPassword` are empty strings…

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, apologies if the questions was a little confusing. 
The issue was that, even though the `password` and `confirmPassword` were both valid and no error text was being displayed, the input box was still red (error color). This was because the formGroup was invalid. I was not referencing the formControl of `confirmPassword`. It is now fix by passing through the `password` and `confirmPassword` as parameters in the validator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of angular material. If there is no error on the given control, `<mat-error>` will not be visible. You need to set the error on the `confirmPassword` field to display the error.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Error was not being set on `confirmPassword` form control

Answer (score 0):

Are all inputs red?

It might be that material input checks if the control is touched or dirty first (before marking it red) but if the form itself is invalid, it marks it red right away.

Looking at the code, it seems that validator at the end of your `registerForm` is ran before the user even gets to filling up the `confirmPassword` field, marking the `registerForm` as invalid.

#### OPTIONS:

1. How about applying the `checkPasswords` validator to `confirmPassword` specifically instead of the whole form?
2. In `checkPasswords`, check if the `confirmPassword` control is touched or dirty as well (aside from `notSame`).

Comment: Hi, I did try this but because I needed the value of `password` I couldn't have the validator inside `confirmPassword`. 

The fix was to pass in password and confirmPassword as params in the function checkPasswords:
`validator: this.checkPasswords('password', 'confirmPassword')`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, all I did was put the mat-error outside of the mat-form-field (literally moved it to the line after the ) and it works fine...so, I guess, putting it at as a direct child of the <form...> rather than a child of the <mat-form-field...>